# How to grab mysql field dynamically via php

Tags: php, mysql

In php I access results from a mysql query results set as such:

```
$results->fldname;
```

My question is how can I dynamically pass the field name to $results? For example:

```
$results->fld_$name;
```

Comment: the question looks incomplete to me unless I am missing something. Are you using a framework?

Comment: @Thecrocodilehunter: could be a simple [PDO object,](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) _(first example)_ This question is pretty clear IMO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
$results->{'fld_'.$name};
//or (not recommended)
$name = 'fld_'.$name;
$results->$name;
```

Comment: Why would you not recommend the second one?

Comment: +1 One could even adapt the first version to `$results->{"fld_$name"}` if so desired, which is closest to the OP's original attempt.

Comment: Suppose you have an array in there, that statement is ambiguous: `$results->$property[1]` can be interpreted as _the second element/character of the value of `$results->$property`_ or _use the second element/character of `$property` as the name_. The curlies are there for clarity. Both for the interpreter and anyone maintaining the code

Comment: Read some more on [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), you can use them to instantiate classes, invoke methods, or plain and simple variables, too: `$name = 'foo';` means that `$$name === $foo`... @eggyal: though that is valid syntax, I dislike using double quotes, because again: with arrays the problem with ambiguity crops up, best to be consistent, and concatenate IMHO. And single quotes are (marginally) faster anyway, since the Zend engine ignores what they contain, doubles are parsed

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking if that's possible in PHP, then yes:

```
$field = "fld_name";
$result->$field;
```

This would be the same as:

```
$result->fld_name;
```